# MySQL View on one machine and a MySQL table in another machine. Query

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a view located in a MySQL database in let us say machine1

I also have another machine with another MySQL database in machine2

The view located in machine1 and the table located in machine2 have the same exact columns.

Is there a way to query both at the same time like so:

select * from view join table1 on view.id = table1.id

```
    string select = "select * from view join table1 on view.id = table1.id";

    OleDbCommand run_select = new OleDbComamnd(select, con);

    OleDbDataReader read_run_select = run_select.ExecuteReader();

etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, 
you can use the CONNECT STORAGE ENGINE. So you can connect to other Server and use it like its on the same machine

Comment: Thanks, I ran a quick google search for "CONNECT STORAGE ENGINE" and everything I'm seeing has to do with MariaDB. Is this exclusively for MariaDB? If it is...it is no big deal the table that is on machine2 I can easily move it to a MariaDB database. Could you provide me with a bit more insight into how this connect storage is used please.

Comment: for MySQL you can use the The FEDERATED Storage Engine , see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html or better switch to MariaDB

Comment: The database with the view I can not change that must remain but the machine with the table I can manipulate.

With your idea of switching could this "CONNECT STORAGE ENGINE" work in a "cross platform" environment? That is to say that I have the views on MySQL but my table in MariaDB?

Comment: On the machine where you want to query an external db server you must have installed MariaDB to use the CONNECT STORAGE ENGINE, but then you can connect to MySQL, MSSQL or much more DBs.